# How can I scroll to a specific character in a Label? (On Android device)

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

Let's say we have a Label that contains some text:

```
<Label x:Name="note_label" TextType="Html" FontSize="18" TextColor="White"/>
```

Is there a way to scroll to a specific character in it?

**PS:** I've only found scroll options in the `ListView`, to a specific page element, and to screen coordinates, but haven't found anything (in Xamarin) that would allow me to scroll to the desired character in the text.

Comment: A Label isn’t a scrollable container.  Are you asking how to make a specific substring visible if the text is too long to fit?

Comment: @Jason Rather a specific symbol, similar to how it is organized in the web page search function (Ctrl+F), you just enter text and you can use the buttons to switch between the search results (with automatic scrolling).

But, if you tell me how to make a certain substring visible, I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: Use a [read-only Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#prevent-text-entry), and set its `CursorPosition`. If your next question is "How do I highlight the search phrase"? This has been asked before. Google `xamarin forms highlight some text`.